# Can not call Static variable

Tags: php

I am brand new to `PHP` and have a simple project, I do Java.
In my simple project I have some `html` files and some `Php` files.
I connect to a device via SSH in my `Php` web page, and after that I am gonna run some commands and return back SSH returned data.
Any ways, So I designed a `Html` file for Login and use that in my `php`, here is my `Php` code :

```
          <?php                
    class Connection {
    public static $ip; // I even made static this variable to test if I can access Static variable from other 
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public static $ssh;


    public  function sshConnection() {
        include ('./view/login.html'); // The html page contain variables 
        include('Net/SSH2.php'); // I use phpseclib to connect via SSH

        if(isset($_POST['lgin'], $_POST['ip'], $_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) { // Login button in html file
            $this->ip = $_POST['ip']; // input type to get ip in html file
            $this->username = $_POST['username']; // input type to get username in html file
            $this->password = $_POST['password']; // input type to get password in html file
            $this->ssh = new Net_SSH2($this->ip);
            if (!$this->ssh->login($this->username, $this->password)) {
                print('Login faild');
            } else {

                header("Location: http://localhost/wireless/configwireless.php"); // This redirect to next page that I should display some Commands
            }
        }
    }
}
    $connection=new Connection();
    $connection->sshConnection();       
        ?>
```

I need $ssh variable in next page so that I can run commands via this connection and make sessions.
I googled and find out I can access the static variable via this code :

```
classname::$variableName;
```

I even made my $ip variable static to test if I can access that or not, But no chance,
Here is my `configwireless.php` Code :

```
<?php
   echo Connection::$ip; // Does not display the input ip variable.

?>
```

But it does not display the `$ip` variable.
Where I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked `$_POST` values?

Comment: try print_r($_POST) and check if the values are being displayed or not'

Comment: Could you explain a little more guys?
I am a little confused. 
:-)

Comment: You can not use it like that. It would work if you set a value to it when defining it. There are no POST variables available in your next page to work with either.

Comment: @RST : Could you give a clear answer or sample by my code?
Thanks.

Comment: change your $ip definition to `public static $ip = '127.0.0.1';` and  you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @RST:  I defined that in the way you said and comment the line $this->ip = $_POST['ip'];
And after that in next page : echo Connection::$ip; 
No chance !

Comment: what you fail to understand, imho, is that when you walk away from one page, you lose the variables created there, unless you push them forward. If you can update your post with proper files names and what is in them, it is easer to explain.

Comment: Ok,One way is to push variable via Post.
I have defined Post method in the login.html form.
And as you see assign it as Post.
Now it goes to next page via Header method.
What should I do to access $ip static variable?

Comment: I even try this in next page : 
echo ($_POST[Connection::$ip]);
NO chance !

Answer (score 0):

For assignment static property in class, should be used ***self*** or ***static*** keyword. So instead of

```
$this->ip = $_POST['ip'];
```

use this

```
static::$ip = $_POST['ip'];
```

or

```
self::$ip = $_POST['ip'];
```

Comment: Could you explain more? Where should i do this?
In declaration or assignment?
Or when want to print?

Comment: Use this in class and assignment of static variable. @me_the_seven

Comment: I did it and now It can not connect via SSH !
It gives me Login failed of If statement !

Comment: Bro, I did that in this way : 
static::$ip = $_POST['ip'];
And this : 
$this->ssh = new Net_SSH2(static::$ip);
And in next page : 
echo Connection::$ip;
But no chance again !

Comment: **ssh** variable is static and use `static::$ssh` instead of `$this->ssh`.

Comment: Note that I made it to non static, The important thing is now the $ip.
If I could access $ip from other page, i can also access $ssh.
Here is what i done in assignment as you said : 
static::$ip = $_POST['ip'];
And to connect also : 
$this->ssh = new Net_SSH2(static::$ip);
And in next page to display the ip variable: 
echo Connection::$ip;
But it does not the $ip value.

Comment: If you redirect page, your variables lost. You redirect to **configwireless.php** and scripts end and send header to user and run another script! So before use of `header("Location: http://localhost/wireless/configwireless.php");`, you must be saved ip another place like in database or session. Another way is not use redirect and use `require 'wireless/configwireless.php'` to show that file.

Comment: Ok sir, thanks, i think its the point,
Could you give a sample? if it is possible in my code? :-? :-D

Answer (score 0):

As my dear friend @Mohammad notice, after `header("Location: http://localhost/wireless/configwireless.php");` variables will be lost.
I did this before  `header("Location: http://localhost/wireless/configwireless.php");`:

```
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['ip'] = $this->ip;
```

And in next page I added :

```
    session_start();
    $x=$_SESSION['ip'];
    echo $x;
```